# not getting sqlsrv in Zend Modules wamp server

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, odbc, wampserver

> I have tried all link of sqlsrv dll for wamp64 but nothing working for me i have Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80

Included the dll's also the dll directory :-

```
extension_dir = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext\"
```

extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

[All my php extension list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iUVE.png)
But i am not getting sqlsrv in Zend Modules
  [my Zend module command list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iUVE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has never released a 64 bit binary for the SQLSRV extension prior to PHP/7 and you are using PHP/5 x64. You need to either upgrade to PHP/7 or downgrade to 32 bits.

The requirements are listed in the [System Requirements for the PHP SQL Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver) you can eventually browse to from the [Introduction](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlsrv.php) section of the PHP manual; x64 DLLs are only listed for SQLSRV 4.0 and above and they're all for PHP/7.0 and later.

Comment: But i have already went through all these can you please help me i m stuck from a long time , Kindly Check my attached images and tell me where am i doing wrong

Comment: I've just double checked your pictures. The problems is that Microsoft has never released a 64 bit binary for the SQLSRV extension prior to PHP/7 and you are using PHP/5 x64. **You need to either upgrade to PHP/7 or downgrade to 32 bits.**

The requirements are listed in the System Requirements for the PHP SQL Driver you can eventually browse to from the Introduction section of the PHP manual; x64 DLLs are only listed for SQLSRV 4.0 and above and they're all for PHP/7.0 and later.